Exporting selected rows from mui/x datagrid as a csv
I am working with the MUI data grid and im trying to implement a feature where I can export all the rows of a csv that I choose.
Here's my current setup for handling row selection and exporting the selected rows:
What I Have Tried:

Checked if onSelectionModelChange is properly bound to the DataGrid.
Verified the MUI DataGrid version and ensured that checkboxSelection is enabled.
Added logging statements to troubleshoot whether the row selection is being registered, but no success.

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { CsvBuilder } from 'filefy';
import SaveAltIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SaveAlt';

const columns = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 90 },
  { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 150 },
  { field: 'email', headerName: 'Email', width: 200 },
  { field: 'phone', headerName: 'Phone Number', width: 150 },
  { field: 'age', headerName: 'Age', width: 110 },
  { field: 'year', headerName: 'Joining Year', width: 150 },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, name: "Neeraj", email: 'neeraj@gmail.com', phone: 9876543210, age: 23, year: 2019 },
  { id: 2, name: "Raj", email: 'raj@gmail.com', phone: 6678901234, age: 17, year: 2020 },
  { id: 3, name: "David", email: 'david342@gmail.com', phone: 6312345678, age: 34, year: 2019 },
  { id: 4, name: "Vikas", email: 'vikas75@gmail.com', phone: 9787654321, age: 20, year: 2021 },
  { id: 5, name: "John", email: 'john@gmail.com', phone: 8976543210, age: 25, year: 2020 },
];

const DataTable = () => {
  const [selectedRowIds, setSelectedRowIds] = useState([]);  // To store selected row IDs
  const [selectedRowData, setSelectedRowData] = useState([]); // To store the actual selected row data

  const handleRowSelection = (newSelection) => {
    const selectedIDs = newSelection;  // Array of selected row IDs
    setSelectedRowIds(selectedIDs);

    const selectedData = rows.filter((row) => selectedIDs.includes(row.id));
    setSelectedRowData(selectedData);  // Set the selected rows data

    console.log("Selected Row IDs:", selectedIDs);
    console.log("Selected Row Data for Export:", selectedData);
  };

  const exportSelectedRows = () => {
    if (selectedRowData.length === 0) {
      alert("No rows selected to export.");
      return;
    }

    new CsvBuilder("selected-rows-data.csv")
      .setColumns(columns.map(col => col.headerName))
      .addRows(selectedRowData.map(row =>
        columns.map(col => row[col.field])
      ))
      .exportFile();
  };

  return (
    <div className="h-96 w-full">
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        checkboxSelection
        pageSize={5}
        onSelectionModelChange={(newSelection) => handleRowSelection(newSelection)}
      />
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className="mt-4"
        startIcon={<SaveAltIcon />}
        onClick={exportSelectedRows}
      >
        Export Selected Rows to CSV
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataTable;


